# How can I have a nested ol continue the alphabetic count?

Tags: html, css

How can I have nested lists indexed like this :

```
-  first
a. firsta
b. firstb
-  second
c. secondc
d. secondd
```

I havent tried anything yet because I'm not sure how to do it and I can't find an answer.
I only did the nested ol.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: disc;
}

ol {
  list-style-type: upper-alpha;
}

li.a {
  font-size: large;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a">Dan Brown</li>
  <ol>
    <li>Κωδικας Da Vinci</li>
    <li>Illuminati</li>
  </ol>
  <li class="a">Paulo Coelho</li>
  <ol>
    <li>Αλχιμιστής</li>
    <li>Έντεκα λεπτά</li>
    <li>Στισ όχθες του ποταμού Πιέδρα...</li>
  </ol>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you specify the question about what you need to achieve.

Comment: Could you try reverse and see 
<ol>
  <li>
    - first
    <ul>
      <li>a. firsta</li>
      <li>b. firstb</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    - second
    <ul>
      <li>c. secondc</li>
      <li>d. secondd</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>

Comment: I want to have a ul that has 3 names  and its marked with disc and in each name to have an ol in alphabetic order that keeps counting the way i do it know it just starts over. btw sorry for my bad english its my second language

Comment: @SanuKhan thats what i was going to do in th first place but its not what my professor wants

Comment: could give me an idea what exactly you want to achieve here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that the code you provided is not semantically valid HTML, even if browsers will try their best to guess your intent. A list can only contain `<li>` elements, which themselves can contain other lists.

To answer your question, if for some reason it makes sense for a list to start at a different index, you can specify it with the `start` HTML attribute on that list. Alternatively, you can specify a `value` attribute on a list item, and the items below it will adjust automatically. Note that the index has to be specified as a number, even if the list-style-type has been changed to use letters.

```css
ul { list-style-type: disc; }
ol { list-style-type: upper-alpha; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    First level 1 item
    <ol>
      <li>First level 2 item</li>
      <li>Second level 2 item</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    Second level 1 item (with start attribute on sublist)
    <ol start="3">
      <li>Third level 2 item</li>
      <li>Fourth level 2 item</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    Third level 1 item
    <ol>
      <li value="5">Fifth level 2 item (with value attribute)</li>
      <li>Sixth level 2 item</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I probably would avoid doing this, however, as you might forget to update these values as you add items to the lists.

Comment: Thanks for your help it fixed my problem im new to html and stack overflow

Comment: My pleasure! I actually had forgotten that lists also have a `start` attribute, I updated the answer with the added information. If an answer was helpful, you can mark it as so using the up arrow on the left, and you can mark your question as solved by clicking the checkmark next to the answer that solved it.

Comment: Oh and in the future, it's always a good idea to check on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol) for information about the element you're trying to use (which might also exist in your first language).